# Error when creating an Excel Workbook in VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to open an Excel workbook through VB.Net using Interop.Excel. I've added the references in my project but I get an error during runtime when I click the "Export" button:

[Runtime Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uThLN.png)

As seen, the error occurs in line 25 which I've indicated in the code below:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel



 Public Class Form1


Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application 'creating instance of excel app
Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form2.Show()




End Sub

Private Sub Export_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Export.Click



    xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add  'ERROR STARTS HERE (Line 25)
    xlSheet = xlWb.Sheets.Add

    If (xlApp Is Nothing) Then

        MsgBox("Excel is not installed on your system!")

    End If






    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.UserControl = True

    xlApp = Nothing
    xlWb = Nothing
    xlSheet = Nothing


End Sub
End Class
```

Also when I rebuild the program, I get the following warning:

[VBIDE Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwIax.png)

I have a feeling this is not related to the program but an issue in Visual Studio but I'm not sure as I've never had this error before until I made this program.

I've tried, as suggested in other forums, to reinstall Office 2013 and also VS 2013 but nothing has changed.

Comment: What if you change `Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application` to `Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application`?

Comment: It still gives me an error

Comment: If I use **Imports Microsoft.Office.Core** and then create an instance of Excel like so: **Dim xlApp As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")** it seems to work without any errors. Why is this?